# Как вывести таблицу с данными из 3 таблиц при помощи JOIN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, sqlite3

Т.е. у меня есть таблица
[image: Табл 1]

Которую нужно вывести и вместе с ней данные ещё из трёх таблиц для столбцов - Марка, Кузов и Трансмиссия,
таблицы одиночные кроме одной, той из которой нужно вывести данные для марки, она выглядит так -
[image: Табл 2]

Отсюда соответственно нужно забрать данные по марке

Таблица кузова -

[image: Табл 3]

И таблица трансмиссии -

[image: Табл 4]

Ну и наконец сие чудо нужно вывести, а выводится оно у меня в таблицу из PyQt5, код -

```
    self.row_count = 1
    self.table_index = 0

    sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("Autosalon.db")
    cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

    sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * FROM Модификация"""
    cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in records:
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.row_count)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[2])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[3])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[4])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 5, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[5])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 6, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[6])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 7, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[7])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 8, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[8])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 9, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[9])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 10, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[10])))

        self.table_index += 1
        self.row_count += 1

    cursor.close()
    sqlite_connection.close()
```

Выводилось как-то так, но нужно выводить как было описано выше )))

Должно получиться -

[image: Пабл 5]

Схема связи -

[image: Схема 1]

Пробую такой запрос -

```
sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * FROM Модификация
                                LEFT JOIN Автомобили ON Модификация.Марка = Автомобили.id
                                LEFT JOIN Кузов ON Модификация.Кузов = Кузов.id 
                                LEFT JOIN Трансмиссия ON Модификация.Трансмиссия = Трансмиссия.id;"""
```

Но, он не подставляет нужные значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к питону, это чистый SQL.
Насколько понимаю все что вам требуется, это добавить выбор колонок в запросе, который вы выполняете:

```
SELECT
  Модификация."Код Модификации",
  Модификация."Скорость",
  Модификация."Разгон",
  Модификация."Объем",
  Модификация."Мощьность",
  Модификация."Расход",
  Автомобили."Марка",
  Модификация."Стоимость",
  Кузов."Кузов",
  Трансмиссия."Трансмиссия"
FROM Модификация
LEFT JOIN Автомобили ON Модификация.Марка = Автомобили.id
LEFT JOIN Кузов ON Модификация.Кузов = Кузов.id 
LEFT JOIN Трансмиссия ON Модификация.Трансмиссия = Трансмиссия.id;
```

Comment: Ага, я уже это сделал, но Автомобили походу всё своё добро хочет вывести по id, нужна именно марка а не всё из Автомобили

Comment: Сейчас немного другим вопросом занимаюсь, если найдёте решение, буду благодарен )

Comment: Так из таблицы Автомобили только Марка и тянется... не совсем понимаю проблемы.

Comment: Всё, разобрался, надо было ещё вывод id подтянуть во всю эту структуру, ругался, что их меньше чем вывожу